# Is there a way to make sure at least ONE of a group of fields is filled, BEFORE sumitting a html form? ("required" is used just to one <input> field)

Tags: html, required

I use "required" if I want that this field (price) is filled before submitting the form:

```
<input required="" type="number" name="price" />
```

How can I make sure that at least one or more fields of a certain group of fields, is filled BEFORE submitting the form? If one field is filled is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Try using require at the end, I believe it will make the entire form required.

```
<input type="number" name="price" required/>
```

Comment: Thanks, but maybe I didn't make myself clear: It would be useful for me if at least one field of the form is filled. With require all fields should be filled.